# Putting a plot next to a question

Tags: diagrams, exam

I would love some help trying to put this graph next to the multi-choice questions.

I am using the `\tasks` command to have it so that the question and graph are next to each other, however now it is not in line with the rest of the stuff above

[image]

Here is the what I have done:

```
\question Find the equation of the following graph 

\begin{tasks}(2)


\task[]

\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice $y = (x-1)(x-5)$ \\
    \choice $y = \frac{4(x-1)(x-5)}{5}$ \\
    \choice $y = x^2 -6x -5$\\
    \choice $\frac{4(x-6)}{5}$
\end{oneparchoices}

\task[] 

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
            xtick={1, 5},
            ytick={4},
            samples=1000,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-1,xmax=7,
            ymin=-3,ymax=6]

\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};

\addplot[name path=F,domain={-1:7}]{((4/5)*(x-1)*(x-5)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tasks}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please post a complete compilable code, with the document class and the package you use. Otherwise we can't adjust our answer to your document...

Comment: So sorry about that- https://www.overleaf.com/read/vkpfnrgmshwm

Comment: Rmano asks you to *post* the compilable code, not provide an external link. Here it's called a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi I am sorry, I am finding this very difficult to explain as well. So, the multi choice for the answers, they are along the same line on the left side of the page for the rest of the questions but you can see that the multi choice answers are slightly to the right on the question (depicted above) compared to the above. It is because I want the graph next to the question but I don't want the multi choice question to be shifted (I am using the tasks to put the parabola next to the questions which is what, I think, is shifting the multi choice answers to the right slightly).

Comment: Please provide some compilable code. You neither state which document class you use (which I assume is `exam`) nor is it clear from the code how `\task` is defined. It would help us tremedously if you could add these information by editing your question. It is difficult to guess what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @user292225, to understand our comments please try the following: a) create a new .tex file, b) copy your posted code into it, c) compile. It doesn't, well ... that's our problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think (but I am not sure, since the code you provide is quite fragmentary) what you aim for might be something like the following:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
        axis line style=thick,
        trig format=rad,
        enlargelimits,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        enlarge y limits=0.15,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)},
            anchor=north west
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(current axis.above origin)},
            anchor=south east
        }
    }
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question Find the equation of the following graph 

\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice $y = (x-1)(x-5)$ \\
    \choice $y = \frac{4(x-1)(x-5)}{5}$ \\
    \choice $y = x^2 -6x -5$ \\
    \choice $\frac{4(x-6)}{5}$
\end{oneparchoices}

\question Find the equation of the following graph 
\hfill\makebox(0.5\linewidth,0pt)[rt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        standard,
        xtick={1, 5},
        ytick={4},
        samples=1000,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xmin=-1, xmax=7,
        ymin=-3, ymax=6
    ]
    
    \node[anchor=center, label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0) {};
    
    \addplot[domain={-1:7}]{((4/5)*(x-1)*(x-5)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice $y = (x-1)(x-5)$ \\
    \choice $y = \frac{4(x-1)(x-5)}{5}$ \\
    \choice $y = x^2 -6x -5$ \\
    \choice $\frac{4(x-6)}{5}$
\end{oneparchoices}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]